# "nVidia GT215 [GeForce GT 320]" graphics card not working on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my old PC. My PC freezes randomly, it might be related to the graphics card. I think I need to install the correct driver. I looked to solution for the problem in this forum, but I was unable to solve it.

`lsmod | grep nvidia` and `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices`does not give any output,but `lspci | grep VGA` gives me following output:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT215 [GeForce GT 320] (rev a2)
```

Output for `sudo lshw -c video`:

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GT215 [GeForce GT 320]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fb000000-fbffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:ce000000-cfffffff ioport:dc00(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Output for  `lsmod | grep nouveau`:

```
nouveau              2367488  0
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
drm_ttm_helper         16384  1 nouveau
ttm                    98304  2 drm_ttm_helper,nouveau
drm_display_helper    184320  1 nouveau
drm_kms_helper        200704  2 drm_display_helper,nouveau
drm                   581632  5 drm_kms_helper,drm_display_helper,drm_ttm_helper,ttm,nouveau
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 nouveau
video                  65536  1 nouveau
wmi                    32768  2 mxm_wmi,nouveau
```

*System Info:*

```
System:
  Host: rgtm-Aspire Kernel: 5.19.0-38-generic x86_64 bits: 64
    Desktop: GNOME 42.5 Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Desktop Mobo: Acer model: Aspire X3950 serial: <superuser required>
    BIOS: American Megatrends v: P01-A3 
CPU:
  Info: dual core model: Intel Core i5 650 bits: 64 type: MT MCP cache:
    L2: 512 KiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 1265 min/max: 1200/3201 cores: 1: 1200 2: 1463 3: 1200
    4: 1200
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GT215 [GeForce GT 320] driver: N/A
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.3 driver: X: loaded: nouveau,vesa
    unloaded: fbdev,modesetting gpu: N/A resolution: 1024x768
  OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.6 128 bits) v: 4.5 Mesa 22.2.5
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel 5 Series/3400 Series High Definition Audio
    driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-2: NVIDIA High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.19.0-38-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet
    driver: r8168
  IF: enp2s0 state: down mac: d0:27:88:0e:a3:f7
  Device-2: Realtek 802.11ac NIC type: USB driver: rtl8821cu
  IF: wlx1cbfce9da648 state: up mac: 1c:bf:ce:9d:a6:48
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 931.51 GiB used: 43.08 GiB (4.6%)
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Western Digital model: WD10EARS-22Y5B1
    size: 931.51 GiB
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 915.32 GiB used: 43.07 GiB (4.7%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda3
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 512 MiB used: 6.1 MiB (1.2%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/sda2
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 2 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) file: /swapfile
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 53.0 C mobo: 20.0 C
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
Info:
  Processes: 231 Uptime: 29m Memory: 11.68 GiB used: 2.16 GiB (18.5%)
  Shell: Bash inxi: 3.3.13
```

Maybe someone here has a solution for this problem?
If you need any further information from me, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What driver does the NVIDIA site say to use for that card on Ubuntu? Says you have no installed driver. Device-1: NVIDIA GT215 [GeForce GT 320] driver: N/A

Comment: Try using these commands: apt search nvidia-driver Check for the tested/recommended option from the list.
Then, sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390 nvidia-dkms-390 **Replace the driver number as per the result you obtain from the first command. Also do `apt update` and `apt upgrade` before running the driver search command.
Lastly, `sudo reboot`, after restart the problem should have been solved. Check this link for reference -> [Link](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-install-nvidia-driver-latest-proprietary-driver/)